# How can I serialize this Python dict?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, flask

I'm trying to serialize a dict (assembled from other dicts) and no matter what I do, I can't seem to serialize this sucker. Json.dumps() throws a type error and says it's unserializable.

Is this a unicode issue or a data type issue? Everything should be a string or int

edits:

- updated the JSON snippet - no formatting, so hopefully no bracket omissions this time)
- the dict is built using context local variables from the Flask-Ask extension for Alexa Skills Kit. So, I mean, if there are unicode / syntax errors in the `{u'foo': u'bar'}` structure, it should be from there.

```
    {'event': {'session': {u'application': {u'applicationId': u'amzn1.ask.skill.9633f809-4141-4cf8-b5f4-5b605e597758'}, u'sessionId': u'amzn1.echo-api.session.68d0c695-bb6c-4929-96d0-6eed0ed9c413', u'user': {u'userId': u'amzn1.ask.account.AGN4D7NM4VKGNCCTCMD3OWT2GR6YKIQF7TODTS4LXUW7UMEVKK6TTKC3JUM25EX3AT4W6WQYCHINGWKWV6TTTNH72U4KL4FH3LXSH3666E3YWPJMYHBDMVDMQZ5SNCIRSTL4BSOMF2V6TNH7I6T4E2NY7IMDPDIIZX3GXDYHZX2NKYELYZE5NE63LJMBAYFE3ZOMRA3F66QYMCY', u'accessToken': u'Atza|IwEBIBFtege3DE13oOO5xiztl3aHcq0mE5dno1lo0p6579-WzNTCNaCvjZicNU-GR5BbDmNWGxjQIk-wnuopeywFQ7vJx-utWTIQrJMXh0AUWJExktH2CiwQmy1sdf9mAvaUTYtTpfxB3J5NGVcE7aeYAMenPiDtSq6yvyjLyjF6V8HqQBxRNiStieHG-YJLCW1oOWs84V143L6wcrgQv5BK-siZAJDcBK_6jiXDFE9cgfIjVpLiSyAH1IqfhJ4-9Gc5CvOAmRVsWCGgxaV-aMntA7FlOnG1eP6ilk81HWRgVusdfy7x7JDxMhEzkHF6l11g9jUFwtAkVIa-9wMedGG6XPFbyNlEbqa6XJuOiawHs9LYDVuAIYRrPyVrF_MANbKApRSrzAX-GFjVC3MSQU48-ySbCxSfo4D5dRlHS8c_3_cFxr8etnEX17HY5G9oC1uYGjEsdfHuDVBUJ3FP65flxRye9zL7S3UBJBwRkxXLiC8iBifb-5sMLnKn7gw8RRe-y3cNCZnCxtmEGzSpHWscxd6v9xsdfdxzf4BXiUaTgpI2oW6JFhXDKotdf_WY-mSsix0URJrwwicC8bQ'}, 'attributes': {'name': u'Foo Bar', 'zip': u'11295', 'userId': u'amzn1.account.AHARAFOFWsdfT7QWD6FXOQRLZR577OA', 'tzid': u'America/New_York', 'lat': 40.6945036, 'lng': -73.9565551, 'email': u'foo@bar.com'}, u'new': 'True'}, 'version': '1.0', 'request': {u'locale': u'en-US', u'timestamp': u'2017-10-20T18:22:42Z', u'type': u'LaunchRequest', u'requestId': u'amzn1.echo-api.request.770f8588-aa1d-443a-b7f6-39abe079e474'}, 'response': {u'version': u'1.0', u'response': {u'outputSpeech': {u'text': u'Welcome to Date Night! Are you staying in or going out?', u'type': u'PlainText'}, u'shouldEndSession': 'False', u'reprompt': {u'outputSpeech': {u'text': u'Hey, Welcome to Date Night! Are you staying in or going out?', u'type': u'PlainText'}}}, u'sessionAttributes': {u'name': u'Foo Bar', u'zip': u'11295', u'userId': u'amzn1.account.AHARAFOsdfsdfsdfFWT7QWD6FXOQRLZR577OA', u'tzid': u'America/New_York', u'lat': 40.6945036, u'lng': -73.9565551, u'email': u'foo@bar.com'}}}}
```

### code:

Here's my code for this function:

```
print ask_version
print ask_session
print ask_request 
print resp # resp is None in this case
ask_session.pop('dialogState', None)
#ask_session['new'] = str(ask_session['new'])

payload = {
    "event" : {
        "version": str(ask_version).encode('utf8'),
        "session": ask_session,
        "request": ask_request
    } 
}

if resp is not None:
    payload['event']['response'] = json.loads(str(resp))
    #payload['event']['response']['response']['shouldEndSession'] = str(payload['event']['response']['response']['shouldEndSession'])

print payload # works fine
print json.dumps(payload) # throws an error
```

---

### console output

```
1.0

{'dialogState': None, u'application': {u'applicationId': u'amzn1.ask.skill.9633f809-4141-4cf8-b5f4-5b605e597758'}, u'sessionId': u'amzn1.echo-api.session.354294b7-78ce-4c47-8673-f671ecb750a6', u'user': {u'userId': u'amzn1.ask.account.AGN4D7NM4VKGNCCTCMD3OWT2GR6YKIQF7TODTS4LXUW7UMEVKK6TTKC3JUM25EX3AT4W6WQYCHINGWKWV6TTTNH72U4KL4FH3LXSH3666E3YWPJMYHBDMVDMQZ5SNCIRSTL4BSOMF2V6TNH7I6T4E2NY7IMDPDIIZX3GXDYHZX2NKYELYZE5NE63LJMBAYFE3ZOMRA3F66QYMCY', u'accessToken': u'Atza|E5dno1lo0p6579-WzNTCNaCvjZicNU-GR5BbDmNWGxjQIk-wnuopeywFQ7vJx-utWTIQrJMXh0AUWJExktH2CiwQmy19mAvaUTYtTpfxB3J5NGVcE7aeYAMenPiDtSq6yvyjLyjF6V8HqQBxRNiStieHG-YJLCW1oOWs84V143L6wcrgQv5BK-siZAJDcBK_6jiXDFE9cgfIjVpLiSyAH1IqfhJ4-9Gc5CvOAmRVsWCGgxaV-aMntA7FlOnG1eP6ilk81HWRgVuy7x7JDxMhEzkHF6l11g9jUFwtAkVIa-9wMedGG6XPFbyNlEbqa6XJuOiawHs9LYDVuAIYRrPyVrF_MANbKApRSrzAX-GFjVC3MSQU48-ySbCxSfo4D5dRlHS8c_3_cFxr8etnEX17HY5G9oC1uYGjEHuDVBUJ3FP65flxRye9zL7S3UBJBwRkxXLiC8iBifb-5sMLnKn7gw8RRe-y3cNCZnCxtmEGzSpHWscxd6v9xdxzf4BXiUaTgpI2oW6JFhXDKotdf_WY-mSsix0URJrwwicC8bQ'}, 'attributes': {'name': u'Foo Bar', 'zip': u'11205', 'userId': u'amzn1.account.AHARAFOFWT7QWD6FXOQRLZR577OA', 'tzid': u'America/New_York', 'lat': 40.99999, 'lng': -73.99999, 'email': u'foo@bar.com'}, u'new': True}

{u'locale': u'en-US', u'timestamp': u'2017-10-20T18:38:32Z', u'type': u'LaunchRequest', u'requestId': u'amzn1.echo-api.request.99b6181b-7e28-4c1d-a49d-ed1f9d0d8c8d'}

None

{'event': {'session': {u'application': {u'applicationId': u'amzn1.ask.skill.9633f809-4141-4cf8-b5f4-5b605e597758'}, u'sessionId': u'amzn1.echo-api.session.354294b7-78ce-4c47-8673-f671ecb750a6', u'user': {u'userId': u'amzn1.ask.account.AGN4D7NM4VKGNCCTCMD3OWT2GR6YKIQF7TODTS4LXUW7UMEVKK6TTKC3JUM25EX3AT4W6WQYCHINGWKWV6TTTNH72U4KL4FH3LXSH3666E3YWPJMYHBDMVDMQZ5SNCIRSTL4BSOMF2V6TNH7I6T4E2NY7IMDPDIIZX3GXDYHZX2NKYELYZE5NE63LJMBAYFE3ZOMRA3F66QYMCY', u'accessToken': u'Atza|E5dno1lo0p6579-WzNTCNaCvjZicNU-GR5BbDmNWGxjQIk-wnuopeywFQ7vJx-utWTIQrJMXh0AUWJExktH2CiwQmy19mAvaUTYtTpfxB3J5NGVcE7aeYAMenPiDtSq6yvyjLyjF6V8HqQBxRNiStieHG-YJLCW1oOWs84V143L6wcrgQv5BK-siZAJDcBK_6jiXDFE9cgfIjVpLiSyAH1IqfhJ4-9Gc5CvOAmRVsWCGgxaV-aMntA7FlOnG1eP6ilk81HWRgVuy7x7JDxMhEzkHF6l11g9jUFwtAkVIa-9wMedGG6XPFbyNlEbqa6XJuOiawHs9LYDVuAIYRrPyVrF_MANbKApRSrzAX-GFjVC3MSQU48-ySbCxSfo4D5dRlHS8c_3_cFxr8etnEX17HY5G9oC1uYGjEHuDVBUJ3FP65flxRye9zL7S3UBJBwRkxXLiC8iBifb-5sMLnKn7gw8RRe-y3cNCZnCxtmEGzSpHWscxd6v9xdxzf4BXiUaTgpI2oW6JFhXDKotdf_WY-mSsix0URJrwwicC8bQ'}, 'attributes': {'name': u'Foo Bar', 'zip': u'11205', 'userId': u'amzn1.account.AHARAFOFWT7QWD6FXOQRLZR577OA', 'tzid': u'America/New_York', 'lat': 40.99999, 'lng': -73.99999, 'email': u'foo@bar.com'}, u'new': True}, 'version': '1.0', 'request': {u'locale': u'en-US', u'timestamp': u'2017-10-20T18:38:32Z', u'type': u'LaunchRequest', u'requestId': u'amzn1.echo-api.request.99b6181b-7e28-4c1d-a49d-ed1f9d0d8c8d'}}}

2017-10-20 11:38:35,551 INFO 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2017 11:38:35] "POST /alexa/ HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_ask/core.py", line 663, in _flask_view_func
    result = self._launch_view_func()
  File "/Users/Neal/Documents/repos/nealrs_heroku/application.py", line 738, in launch
    dashbot("incoming")
  File "/Users/Neal/Documents/repos/nealrs_heroku/application.py", line 665, in dashbot
    print json.dumps(payload)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 244, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: {u'application': {u'applicationId': u'amzn1.ask.skill.9633f809-4141-4cf8-b5f4-5b605e597758'}, u'sessionId': u'amzn1.echo-api.session.354294b7-78ce-4c47-8673-f671ecb750a6', u'user': {u'userId': u'amzn1.ask.account.AGN4D7NM4VKGNCCTCMD3OWT2GR6YKIQF7TODTS4LXUW7UMEVKK6TTKC3JUM25EX3AT4W6WQYCHINGWKWV6TTTNH72U4KL4FH3LXSH3666E3YWPJMYHBDMVDMQZ5SNCIRSTL4BSOMF2V6TNH7I6T4E2NY7IMDPDIIZX3GXDYHZX2NKYELYZE5NE63LJMBAYFE3ZOMRA3F66QYMCY', u'accessToken': u'Atza|E5dno1lo0p6579-WzNTCNaCvjZicNU-GR5BbDmNWGxjQIk-wnuopeywFQ7vJx-utWTIQrJMXh0AUWJExktH2CiwQmy19mAvaUTYtTpfxB3J5NGVcE7aeYAMenPiDtSq6yvyjLyjF6V8HqQBxRNiStieHG-YJLCW1oOWs84V143L6wcrgQv5BK-siZAJDcBK_6jiXDFE9cgfIjVpLiSyAH1IqfhJ4-9Gc5CvOAmRVsWCGgxaV-aMntA7FlOnG1eP6ilk81HWRgVuy7x7JDxMhEzkHF6l11g9jUFwtAkVIa-9wMedGG6XPFbyNlEbqa6XJuOiawHs9LYDVuAIYRrPyVrF_MANbKApRSrzAX-GFjVC3MSQU48-ySbCxSfo4D5dRlHS8c_3_cFxr8etnEX17HY5G9oC1uYGjEHuDVBUJ3FP65flxRye9zL7S3UBJBwRkxXLiC8iBifb-5sMLnKn7gw8RRe-y3cNCZnCxtmEGzSpHWscxd6v9xdxzf4BXiUaTgpI2oW6JFhXDKotdf_WY-mSsix0URJrwwicC8bQ'}, 'attributes': {'name': u'Foo Bar', 'zip': u'11205', 'userId': u'amzn1.account.AHARAFOFWT7QWD6FXOQRLZR577OA', 'tzid': u'America/New_York', 'lat': 40.99999, 'lng': -73.99999, 'email': u'foo@bar.com'}, u'new': True} is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: You are mixing `str` and `unicode` types, if this is Python 2..

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure this has unbalanced brackets...

Comment: i dont think that matters @juanpa.arrivillaga (str and unicode mix) ... it should still be json serializeable

Comment: `u 'application'` (and tons of others) looks like `SyntaxError` to me.

Comment: Post the actual error.

Comment: you have a space after every `u` ... that is a syntax error ...

Comment: There is missing bracket at the end of snippet.

Comment: Yes, actually, this simply isn't a valid Python literal. How is this being generated? Are you creating this by hand?

Comment: @JoranBeasley you're right, that was my first thought, but it's not surprising that this is handled as one would hope. Clearly, though, this is simply invalid as you've pointed out.

Comment: and yes, i am using python2

Comment: `json.dumps` has no problem with the new data. Tested on Python 2.6.6 and Python 3.6.0

Comment: @PM2Ring hunh, still having trouble on my end i added my code + console output. thanks for taking a look!

Comment: @Iguananaut - updated with error info. thx

Comment: Is it possible that one of these values is an instance of a `dict`-*like* class that is not actually `dict` subclass?  E.g. what does `print(type(ask_session))` return?

Comment: @Iguananaut looks like they are `<class 'werkzeug.local.LocalProxy'>` (i really thought they were dicts.

Comment: Aha! That was my suspicion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like jsonify & dict() aren't smart enough to deal with Flask's context locals (`<class 'werkzeug.local.LocalProxy'>`). Only thing that worked for me was using `._get_current_object()` to access the proxy as a dict. Plug that into `json.dumps()` and you'll be good.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you'll encounter objects that *look* like a normal `dict` when printed, but really aren't.  This is especially common in web frameworks.  Try converting it to a normal `dict` that the `json` module knows how to serialize like:

```
ask_session = dict(ask_session)
```

One problem that may occur is if you have a nested data structure.  In that case it might be good to add a custom encoder for that type.  See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3768975/982257

It may not be necessary though.  Flask has a built-in utility function called [`jsonify`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.json.jsonify) that knows how to handle a lot of types that show up in Flask.  I haven't tested it in this case, but I almost always use it when I'm writing Flask apps.

Comment: looked through the context local doc and it seems like  `ask_version._get_current_object()` is the right way to do this. Finally generated valid json! thanks a ton for suggesting that maybe my dicts weren't actually dicts.

Comment: Try `jsonify` though, if you haven't.  It might already handle this.